# Powershell positioning buttons / Powershell button alignment

Tags: powershell

I'd like to position a button in the lower right corner of the window and it shall stay there even when resizing?

The button opens a new window and it works:

```
$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Text = "Config" 
$Button.Width = 147
$Button.Height = 32
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(400,400)
$Button.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$Button.Add_Click({[void] $NewWindow.ShowDialog()})
$MainWindow.Controls.Add($Button)
```

But I don't know how to align it or snap it onto the lower right corner.

@Peter Schneider

```
$Button.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Bottom -bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Right
```

Does work half way, but you can't make the window smaller after you increased the size.

@Dan Stef

```
$MainWindow = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$MainWindow.StartPosition = "Manual"
$MainWindow.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(640,480)
$MainWindow.Text = "Computerstatus"
$MainWindow.AutoSize = $True
$MainWindow.KeyPreview = $True
```

Comment: Can you add the definition for `$mainwindow`? So I can test it on my computer and play around.

Comment: If you feel adventurous you can try using WPF instead of Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#The missing includes
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

#AutoSize and Anchor don't work together (they are exclusive)
$MainWindow.AutoSize = $true

$Button.Anchor = 'right,bottom'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Anchor Property and AnchorStyles enumeration:

```
$button.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Bottom -bor
[System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Right
```

Comment: Thanks, but it only lets me increase the windowsize.